# Plotting large dataset as graph in android

Tags: android, graph, plot

I need to plot daily prices as graph in an android application. 
For 30 day graph, I am simply fetching all 30 data points from the server and plotting it.

For 3(90 data points), 6(180 data points), 12(360 datapoints) month graph, I am worried that it could increase the data download.

What are the standard options to reduce amount of data being transferred? 
Is there any way I can generate one data point for n days and send them over the wire?

Answer (score 0):

Are these images? Why not generate the images server-side, and then ship out the prebuilt images? You can have the application ask for the images over an AJAX-y call.

Comment: If we transfer image, zoom in & out does not give clear clarity.

Comment: How about using a vector based graphic (SVG) instead of a bitmap based graphic? If all you want is zooming, this would work. If you want the ability to manipulate data, then I think you should look into compressing the datapoints.

Comment: I changed the data format and able to reduce datagram size from 16MB to 6 MB. I am testing it on real devices to see the latency.           Do you have any pointers on how to generate SVG?

Comment: If you're using Java, I'd highly recommend looking into a SVG-generating class/library. I used one a LONG time ago for Java that was called JFreeChart which might work for you. Here's what I did with JFreeChart:  

http://brian-stinar.blogspot.com/2009_08_01_archive.html